# Illustrator: how to image trace photo to vector artwork

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, image-trace

I have an image which I turn to vector with `Image Trace > High Fidelity Photo`.

What happens is that now I can really resize it how ever I want, but its still acts as an image, showing with a large X over it, so I can't really edit in detail.

Is there a away to really turn it into a vector so its not "grouped"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, select the image and go to Object > Expand > OK.

Answer (score 3):

You must Expand your image after tracing. Then just ungroup and you're done.

[image: blobby]

Comment: Haha, it's not a race^^ The important thing is that you got your answer